# Best way to add the same information to more items on a list

Tags: lists, dropdown

Imagine we have a list of people. They are to do a task. I have the option of giving them
extra time. I could give Peter an extra 5 minutes for example.

[image]

What is a good way to give all people an extra 5 minutes?

"Extra time" could be a drop-down of sorts that controls the extra time of all the people in the list.

Any other ideas or known standards/conventions in this area?

Comment: How many 'extra time' amounts are there, or could it be any amount of time? (Meaning - can you only give people 5 extra minutes, or can you give John 5 minutes, Peter 15 minutes, Ida 12 minutes and Sarah 100 minutes?)

Comment: You can give all people a different amount of extra time. Lets say the options are 5 minutes, 10 minutes and 15 minutes. Now you want to give everyone 15 minutes of extra time and then change Ida's amount to 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

What comes to mind here is a selection box for each list item, and then apply the change for all selected items (people).

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnfVVg.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

You display the members of the list, together with their extra/remaining time. You provide selection boxes for each item (maybe with a SELECT ALL-box above), when selection is triggered the action panel above the list is enabled (which could provide more features than "Add extra time). The user choose which action to perform on the selection, this triggers a input field to appear (not on top of the list hiding the table, but adjacent to it) where the user can specify the update. The user can now perform directed action on multiple items in one flow.

Comment: Of the two answers, I agree with this one more because it allows more flexibility. I'm designing something exactly like this for a very similar purpose, and doing it exactly as AndroidHustle pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You could use preset control, which contains both extra time settings, and reset option, see the image:

[image]

This is one-click solution and doesn't require any chechboxes. Of course, it's less flexible.